# What files to copy for a raw MySQL database backup

Tags: mysql

I am creating a backup script that will do a raw (file copy) based backup of MySQL 5.7 databases on Windows. I am doing this, because the databases are large (300GB), and mysqldump will create large dumps and take a lot of time.

Lets assume I only have one database named mydb. **Edit**: MySQL is stopped at the time of the file copy.

I am creating a copy of the following files:

- [sqldatadir]\mydb\ (full directory)
- [sqldatadir]\mysql\ (full directory)
- [sqldatadir]\ibdata1

Is this all I need, or am I missing files?
The ibtmp1 files are create at startup right?

Comment: You sure this will work properly when the database is running? Unless you stop the database before copying the files. There is an excellent tool to do the hot backup called [xtrabackup](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.4/index.html), and guess what, it's free.

Comment: correct what @emix says - use xtrabackup. it can also create incremental backups.

Comment: I am stopping the database machine before doing the backup. Great suggestion @emix, I will look into it. In the meantime I still would like to know whether I am having my file list complete